# Complex type & SilverLight & WCF RIA - most easy way?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I try to operate with WCF RIA + SilverLight (Entity FrameWork + DomainService)
On SQL server I have three tables:

**users**
idName
idUser

**usersStatus**
idStatus
idUser

**usersJobs**
idJobs
idUser

So, I have three entities on server/client-side.
Is there a way to get all three entities at once, in one object?

I want to do it by Domain Service side, by LINQ (not at SQL Server)?

I tried to create specail proxy-class, but feel trouble to create an instance.
Field of proxy-class define in metadata - so I can not get access to it.

I want for example something like that:

```
public partial class proxyUser
{
internal sealed class proxyUserMetadata
    {

        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private proxyUserMetadata()
        {
        }

        public users user { get; set; }

        public usersStatus status{ get; set; }

        public EntityCollection <usersJobs> jobs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is there easy way? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new class to wrap entities you want to return to client.

```
public class CustomEntity
{
    [Key]
    public Users User { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
    public List<UserJobs> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I would move the userId out as a separate property and make it the key. It seems everything is bound to it anyway.

Comment: @Danexxtone I totally agree with you, in fact it'd be easy if this guy use ASPNetMembership but I don't know about the design decision so I leave it out there.